# control on a java-fx Button by 'Advice' class on aop spring framework

Tags: spring, javafx, aop

im trying to acsess an application button on javafx program by extenal 'Aspect' class using the spring aop .

This is the aspect class:

```
public class AspectControl {

    private List<String> UserClicks;
    private String[] expectedClick={"yellow","greean","red","blue","blue","blue","grean"};


    public void beforeClickYellow(){
        UserClicks.add("yellow");
    }

    public void afterClickYellow(){
        Thread t=new Thread();
        Main.yellowBtn.disableProperty();
    }

}
```

this is the configuration xml :

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:aop = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd ">
  <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
   <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id ="aspectcontrol" ref = "control">
     <aop:pointcut id ="YellowPointcut" 
        expression = "execution(* 
              application.ButtonsNotify.yellowNotify(..))"/>


     <aop:before pointcut-ref ="YellowPointcut" method="beforeClickYellow"/>  
     <aop:after  pointcut-ref ="YellowPointcut" method ="afterClickYellow"/>      


  </aop:aspect>
```

application class:

```
package application;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;

import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.CycleMethod;
import javafx.scene.paint.LinearGradient;
import javafx.scene.paint.Stop;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.scene.transform.Translate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final int SCENE_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int SCENE_HEIGHT = 500;

    private Group GroupButtns;
    private final int TOTAL_CLICKS = 10;
    private int numOfClick = 0;

    public static Button yellowBtn;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) {
        stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        stage.sizeToScene();
        stage.setScene(new AppScene());

        //close application
        final Button close = new Button("X");
        close.setFont(Font.font("Arial", FontWeight.BOLD, 20));
        close.setStyle("-fx-background-color:transparent;-fx-text-fill:red;");
        close.setOpacity(0);
        close.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        close.setTranslateY(stage.getScene().getHeight() - 20);

        stage.getScene().setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                close.setOpacity(1);
            }
        });
        stage.getScene().setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
                close.setOpacity(0);
            }
        });

        // close application
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(new EventHandler<WindowEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(WindowEvent t) {
                Platform.exit();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        yellowBtn = new Button();
        SetButnView(yellowBtn, "yellow");
        yellowBtn.setTranslateY(stage.getScene().getHeight() - 250);
        yellowBtn.setTranslateX(stage.getScene().getX() - 200);

        yellowBtn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {

                numOfClick += 1;
                ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("BeanConfig.xml");

                ButtonsNotify notify = (ButtonsNotify) context.getBean("btnNotify");
                notify.yellowNotify(numOfClick);

            }
        });

        Button blueBtn = new Button();
        SetButnView(blueBtn, "blue");
        blueBtn.setTranslateY(stage.getScene().getHeight() - 250);
        blueBtn.setTranslateX(stage.getScene().getX() - 10);

        Button redbtn = new Button();
        SetButnView(redbtn, "red");
        redbtn.setTranslateY(stage.getScene().getHeight() - 420);
        redbtn.setTranslateX(stage.getScene().getX() - 10);

        Button greenbtn = new Button();
        SetButnView(greenbtn, "green");
        greenbtn.setTranslateY(stage.getScene().getHeight() - 420);
        greenbtn.setTranslateX(stage.getScene().getX() - 200);


        GroupButtns.getChildren().add(close);
        GroupButtns.getChildren().add(yellowBtn);
        GroupButtns.getChildren().add(blueBtn);
        GroupButtns.getChildren().add(greenbtn);
        GroupButtns.getChildren().add(redbtn);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private class AppScene extends Scene {

        public AppScene() {
            super(GroupButtns = new Group(), SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT, Color.TRANSPARENT);
            GroupButtns.setClip(new Ellipse(0, SCENE_HEIGHT / 2, SCENE_WIDTH / 3, SCENE_HEIGHT / 2)); //Scene shape and size
            Rectangle background = new Rectangle(-SCENE_WIDTH / 2, 0, SCENE_WIDTH, SCENE_HEIGHT);
            background.setFill(new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, SCENE_HEIGHT, false, CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE, new Stop(0, Color.GRAY), new Stop(0.3, Color.GRAY),
                    new Stop(1., new Color(1, 1, 1, 0)))); //background color
            GroupButtns.getChildren().add(background);
            GroupButtns.getTransforms().addAll(new Translate(SCENE_WIDTH / 2, SCENE_HEIGHT), new Rotate(180));
        }
    }

    public void SetButnView(Button btn, String color) {
        if (color.equals("yellow")) {
            Image src = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("yellow1.png"));
            btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(src));
        }
        if (color.equals("blue")) {
            Image src = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("blue1.png"));
            btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(src));
        }

        if (color.equals("red")) {
            Image src = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("red1.png"));
            btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(src));
        }

        if (color.equals("green")) {
            Image src = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("green1.png"));
            btn.setGraphic(new ImageView(src));
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the poincut class which I call every time I press a btn on the application class:

```
package application;

public class ButtonsNotify  {

    public ButtonsNotify(){

    }

    public void yellowNotify(int clickNumber){
        System.out.println("yellow");
    }

    public void RedNotify(int clickNumber){
        System.out.println("red");
    }

    public void BlueNotify(int clickNumber){
        System.out.println("blue");
    }

    public void GreenNotify(int clickNumber){
        System.out.println("green");
    }

}
```

How can I control the button's visability by the 'AspectControl' class??